# regular expression for adjacent same character

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm looking for a regular expression pattern that can match adjacent 2 same characters, (used for grepping in Linux).
For example:
Catt
Puppet
Worry
Fool

Answer (score 3):

Something like this with GNU grep?

```
echo 'Catt Puppet Worry Fool' | grep -E '(.)\1'
```

or

```
echo 'Catt Puppet Worry Fool' | grep -oE '(.)\1'
```

**Update:**

Try this to get the complete words:

```
echo 'Catt Puppet Worry Fool' | grep -Po '[^ ]*(.)\1[^ ]*'
```

Comment: Thanx Ctrus but this cmd will only grep the adjacent letters but i need the whole word which has adjacent letter
eg: **echo 'Catt Puppet Worry Bulb Fool Nano' | grep -oE '(.)\1'** Output should be :
Catt
Puppet
Worry
Fool

Comment: Try `grep -Eo '\<[[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]])\1[[:alnum:]]*\>'` to grab the containing word. If the POSIX *alnum* class is not suitable for your definition of "word", substitute it with something which is.

Comment: The revised answer is better than my proposal. No need to switch from `-E` to `-P` though.

Comment: @tripleee: Thank you. Yes, `-E` is adequate .